# The instructions at 0xXXXXXXXX referenced memory at 0xXXXXXXXX, The memory could not be written

Tags: c#, .net, hook

I get this error when trying to implement a windows hook using SetWindowsHookEx and CallWndProc. I'm wondering if i implemented the hook correctly. Here is the code: This code will work as a keyboard hook if its replaced with LowLevelKeyboardProc

---

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, CallWndProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    private delegate IntPtr CallWndProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4;
    const int WM_PASTE = 0x302;
    private CallWndProc _proc = hookProc;

    private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public void SetHook()
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, _proc, hInstance, 0);
    }

    public static void UnHook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
    }

    public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_PASTE)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paste");
            return (IntPtr)1;
        }
        else
            return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam);
    }

    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        UnHook();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetHook();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module handle passed to SetWindowsHookEx should be the handle for your dll, not "user32".

Comment: I like how this is the first sentence in the documentation of the `hInstance` parameter, yet the OP missed it. Note also that injected global hooks should not be written in managed code. And there is a missing `UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr` annotation, which creates the risk that the delegate gets moved by GC while the hook is installed.